# Sharing USB device over ethernet to virtual machine

Tags: usb, virtual-machines, remote-control

I need to control some USB smartcard readers from a virtual machine (linux), can you recommend a device with good drivers to let the VM see the physical USB devices connected like a physical computer?

Comment: Please elaborate this question. You want to connect USB(Pendrives) to Vm Machines which works like physical. is that so?

Comment: I have to connect a physical smartcard reader to a VM. But I cannot use directly its host. Then I'm looking for something like a general USB sharing device over network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a device with at least one USB port. Any USB device connected to that ”hub“ will be ”shared“ to the VM. If that's the case, I suggest you to search the internet for the following word combinations:

- `USB over IP`
- `USB over ethernet`
- `ethernet USB device server`
- `ethernet USB sharing station`

I've seen deviced by these brands: [Silex](https://www.silextechnology.com/connectivity-solutions/device-connectivity), [SEH](https://www.seh-technology.com/products/usb-device-servers.html), [coolgear](https://www.coolgear.com/product-category/hubs-2/usb-over-ethernet), [DIGI](https://www.digi.com/products/networking/usb-connectivity/usb-over-ip), [SIIG](https://www.siig.com/it-products/device-server/usb-over-ip.html), [StarTech](https://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/USB-PS2/10-100-1000-Mbps-Gigabit-1-Port-USB-over-IP-Device-Server~USB1000IP).

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any suggestion about reliability of those brands?

Comment: I'm afraid, no. But in any case I'd advice you to analyse and compare by yourself. For example, read the specs, check out the user guides, discover the other products of the company/brand, etc. pp. I guess you'll find guides on the internet on how to assess the reliability of hardware.